# Having one file non-https on https site and how to write the code in the htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, https, url-rewriting

Our software uses a file on our website to check if it is valid and is hardcoded into the software, I want our site to go to https but want the directory for this file left as http.

Comment: Please elaborate your question more, I cannot really understand what do you want.

Comment: I want my entire site to be https://examplesite.com, but there is one directory http://examplesite.com/file.txt that can be accessed without redirecting to https version of the site.

Comment: Did you fine the answer useful for what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add .htaccess to your website root directory with following configuration:

```
# This will enable the Rewrite capabilities
RewriteEngine On

# This checks to make sure the connection is not already HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on

# This checks file name is not file.txt
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !file.txt

# This redirects to all requests to https 
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

Please check this [reference](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS) for more info.

Comment: Do I have to use the full extension to the file. I can't test because it breaks the link to the software straight away and people are unable to log in. For example it is was www.siteexample.com/services/files/file.txt would I have to put !/services/files/file.txt or just !file.txt. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No, you don't need to, actually the above checks if the request file name, DOES NOT CONTAIN `file.txt`, so it works with `www.siteexample.com/services/files/file.txt` and works with `www.siteexample.com/services/file.txt` and `www.siteexample.com/file.txt`